# HTML | Moving an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make place the down arrow image to near the bottom of the sky background. I also want it to stay in the position when the window is resized.( I want it to be a splash screen with an arrow at the bottom that when clicked moves down to the next section)

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>particles.js demo</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="particles-js" width='100%'></div>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/index.js">
</script>
<img id='downarrow' height="75" width="75" src='images/arrowdown.png'>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
body {
margin: 0;
height: 2000px;
width: 100%;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}
#particles-js {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #00a4ff;
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/yHL4C4u.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

#downarrow {
margin-left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
img {
position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` will put something at the bottom/center.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #00a4ff;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/yHL4C4u.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#downarrow {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>particles.js demo</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="particles-js" width='100%'></div>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="js/index.js">
  </script>
  <img id='downarrow' height="75" width="75" src='images/arrowdown.png'>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are a legend man, thanks so much! Is there anyway i can +rep you or something!

Comment: @vkaylum no problem! Just upvote and accept my answers if they help and answer your question.